# Parsing a JSON Result with exhaustive list

Tags: java, android, json

Good day, i am trying to parse this JSONObject returned from the OpenWeatherMap forecast API. this is the link [link here](http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?id=524901)

now it returns an exhaustive list of results and i just want to get the results for each day at rough 12:00 with the key "dt_txt". i was thinking of something like parsing only the dates and comparing with a date method that increments the current day in a loop and if it matches, i then parse the values for that day. But i wanted to know if there is a better, faster and more efficient solution to achieve this.
Many thanks.

Comment: The API also supports limiting by number of days e.g. http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?id=524901&cnt=1&mode=json returns the forecast for 1 day in future (i.e. tomorrow)

Comment: @Ridcully ok. maybe i did not phrase the question correctly but am not really talking about speed here. i know its fast i was talking of an easier way to parse the results and obtain what i need

Comment: What could be easier than a `new JSONObject(textFromYourLink)` and then iterating over the items of "list"?

Comment: @SoftwareGuy thanks i kind of missed that one.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tested how long a simple `new JSONObject(textFromYourLink)` takes? Is it even necessary to optimize the speed?

If there is actually, some need for optimization, I'd suggest that you do some pre-processing of the text and, using some regular expressions, get rid of the parts you don't need. After that, you still can convert the remaining string to a `JSONObject` which should be done faster now.